# How to run a function in a chained `.then()`?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, asynchronous

I'm with trouble in run a function in a chained `.then()` once the functions are asynchronous.

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Home";
import Search from "./Search";
import * as BooksAPI from "./BooksAPI";

import "./App.css";

class BooksApp extends React.Component {
  state = {
    books: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    BooksAPI.getAll().then(books => {
      this.setState({ books: books });
    });
  }

  changeShelf = (book, shelf) => {
    BooksAPI.update(book, shelf);

    BooksAPI.getAll().then(books => {
      this.setState({ books: books });
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app">
        <Switch>
          <Route
            exact
            path="/"
            render={() => (
              <Home books={this.state.books} changeShelf={this.changeShelf} />
            )}
          />

          <Route
            path="/search"
            render={() => (
              <Search changeShelf={this.changeShelf} books={this.state.books} />
            )}
          />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default BooksApp;
```

The comment is specific about this part of the code:

```
changeShelf = (book, shelf) => {
  BooksAPI.update(book, shelf);

  BooksAPI.getAll().then((books) => {

    this.setState({
      books: books
    })

  })

}

render() {

    return (
```

Next, I show to you the comment I've received:

[image: Reviewer comment about 'Asynchronous' Function]

Comment: The comment has told you what you need to do, with reference to other code you've already written. What exactly is unclear?

Comment: It's similar to the way you already chain `BooksAPI.getAll().then()`.

Comment: Hi, @jonrsharpe, thanks for the feedback. I'd like a suggestion, 'cause I'm not being able to implement exactly what I've done before. I've tried many ways, and haven't get. Maybe there some diferent detail I'm not seeing, I don't know.

Comment: Then show a [mcve] of what you've tried, and what exactly the problem with it is. Or ask the reviewer for more specific feedback.

Comment: I'm confused. The post shows a comment with the correct way to do this. What is the issue?

Comment: Sorry, @jonrsharpe. Maybe I didn't well format my question. And I've got -3 vote for me instead. My bad. 
I'll pay attention on this in the future. Sorry, again.

Comment: Sorry, @tdelam. As I've said to jonrsharpe, I think I haven't well formated the question. I'm new in the comunity, so sorry for the mistake.

Comment: @jose-renato-m no worries, I am just not sure what's missing here. It seems like you have your answer already, no?

Comment: @tdelam, as I've said above, 'asynchrounism' sometimes makes my brain spin, as I'm a noob in programming yet. Maybe you're right and the answer is in my face (with the reviewer comment) and I'm not being able to see it......:-(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Put `BooksAPI.getAll` inside the then-block of `BooksAPI.update` as suggested already.

```
BooksAPI.update(book, shelf).then(()=>{
  BooksAPI.getAll().then((books) => {

    this.setState({
      books: books
    })

  })
});
```

Comment: I'm not writing this three times, and I cannot believe *none* of you know this, but: if you actually return the promise, you don't have to create the classic callback pyramid with `.then`s.

Comment: So you are telling me that the code already works? I doubt that strongly. Both methods will be fired almost at the same time asynchronously.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I actually did know that. But the above code is still the solution considering the provided error message of the tutorial or what ever that is. Its not the best solution but its what this tutorial expects.

Comment: It's stylistically poor (given our previous comments) and doesn't take into account the whole solution provided in the question itself.

Comment: @Emile Bergeron, I'm thinking in callback hell and have done wrongly. I'm trying to improve the code accordingly, as suggested by the reviewer.

Answer (score -1):

The issue here is that order of execution for `BooksAPI.update` and `BooksAPI.getAll` isn't guaranteed because both of them return a Promise instance - they are executed asynchronously.
If your intention is to (first) update a book and (then) get all books, code should looks similar to this:

```
BooksAPI.update(book, shelf)
    .then(() => {
        BooksAPI.getAll()
            .then(allBooks => this.setState({ books: allBooks }));
    });
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58942828/how-to-run-a-function-in-a-chained-then#comment104144283_58942920